# How do I extract the access_token from an http respnse in Microsoft Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio, http

This is what the http response will look like:

```
Http/1.1 200 OK
{
"access_token": "<token-value-here>",
  "expires_in": 300,
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

I would like to get the token by making the request and getting the token, then make that token value a variable to use in my remaining API tests so I don't have to keep calling for a new one.

I would like to do this using Microsoft Visual Studio Code. Is this possible?

Comment: When you say you want to do this from Visual Studio Code, what do you mean?

Comment: This is what I am using: https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Comment: I know the program :) But I'm unsure what you mean. Do you want to do this in a particular programming language? Do you want to use the integrated terminal? What have you tried so far?

Comment: We have many API calls to test and need to add a token for each call. The API calls are setup and they work. The problem is we need to fill in the token for each call after we get a new one. I thought there would be a way to first get the token manually then set it as a variable and call that variable for the token value i neach call. First we'd like to get this done. Then the ultimate goal of this is automation, which is much later down the road.

Comment: Here is a sample call in MSVS Code: 
###
GET <API CALL HERE>
Authorization: Bearer <token-value>